# Magento 2 how to get Purchase Point from order collection factory?

Tags: magento2, order-collection

I'm trying to get order purchase point (store where it was purchased), I have tried this:

```
$order->getPurchasePoint();
```

It did not work, any ideas?

here is my code

```
 public function execute()
    {
       
        $date = date('m-d-Y');
        $filepath = 'export/orders-'.$date.'.csv';
        $this->directory->create('export');
        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
 
        $header = ['Id', 'Status','Store'];
        $stream->writeCsv($header);
        $collection = $this->getOrderCollection();
        
        foreach ($collection as $order) {
            $data = [];
            $data[] = $order->getId();
            $data[] = $order->getStatus();
            $data[] = $order->getPurchasePoint();
            $stream->writeCsv($data);
        }


    }

    public function getOrderCollection() 
    {
    $collection = $this->orderCollection->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setOrder('created_at','desc');
    return $collection;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the way.

This is the way to get the storeview name of the order and the name.

```
$store_name = $_order->getStore()->getGroup()->getName()  //store name
$store_view_name = $_order->getStore()->getName();
```

In this website you can find more methods

https://www.rootways.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-get-store-information-of-order